# Why this script doesn't produce the result

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to search report of pending payment of John Jackson of year 2013, but it doesn't produce the result.

This suppose to be when I insert `name=John Jackson`, `class=grade one`, and `year=2013`, the query suppose to check in setting table the setting field values of  `year= 2013` and subtract the amount payed by John from payment table of 2013.

I have these two tables 'payment and setting'

```
Note that I'w mention some of fields
```

payment table (used to store payment information)

```
id  fname        class     school_fee boarding exam_paper lunch date        year
1   John Jackson Grade one 100000     300000   30000      1000  2013-12-12  0000-00-00
```

setting table(used to store actual payment of service per one year)

```
id boarding_setting exampaper_setting fee_setting lunch_setting  year       date
1  200000           30000             200000      180000         2013-12-18 NULL 
   300000           40000             300000      190000         2014-12-12 NULL
```

In setting table I put actual payment of certain service for one year so that when student pay example(school_fee) the fee_setting field in setting table will minus the amount of school_fee payed in payment table according to year posted.

Here php script Join two table and query the info from tables;

```
  <?php include("../Connections/conn.php")?>                       
    <?php
    $fname="fname";
    $date="date";
    $class="class";

    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $date=$_POST['year'];
    $class=$_POST['class'];


     $sql2="SELECT SUM(boarding)as boarding,SUM(exam_paper)as 
     exam_paper,SUM(school_fee)as  
     school_fee,SUM(lunch)as lunch,fname,class,date,year  
     FROM payment
     WHERE YEAR(date) = '$date' AND fname like '%".$fname."%' AND class like 
    '%".$class."%' AND    
     date like '%".$date."%' UNION  
     SELECT(boarding_setting,exampaper_setting,fee_setting,lunch_setting,year,date   
      ) 
    FROM setting WHERE YEAR(date) = '$date' AND fname like '%".$fname."%' AND class 
    like  '%".$class."%' AND date like '%".$date."%'"; 

    $q=mysql_query($sql2);  

      }
    else{
   $sql="SELECT * FROM payment";
   $q=mysql_query($sql);
      }
       ?>
```

This the form I use to input search information

```
<form method="post">
<table width="500" border="0">
<tr>
<td>Student name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $fname;?>" /></td>

<td>Class</td>
<td><input type="text" width="10" name="class" value="<?php echo $class;?>" /></td>


<td>Year</td>
<td><input type="number" name="year" value="<?php echo $date;?>" /></td>

<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" /></td>
```

This the echo script

```
<?php
while(!empty($q) and $res=mysql_fetch_array($q)){   
?>
<tr>
    <td width="15%"><?php echo $res['fname'];?></td>
    <td width="8%"><?php echo $res['class'];?></td>
     <td width="10%"><?php echo $res['boarding_setting']- $res['boarding'];?></td>
     <td width="10%"><?php echo $res['exampaper_setting']- $res['exam_paper'];?></td>
     <td width="8%"><?php echo $res['fee_setting']- $res['school_fee'];?></td>
     <td width="10%"><?php echo $res['lunch_setting']- $res['lunch'];?></td>
    <td width="10%" style="border-width:medium"><?php echo $res['date'];?></td>
</tr>

<?php }?>
```

Comment: Debug it: check that **every** line in your script does what it's supposed to

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% Sure this will even work. If I were you I would start looking at using MYSQLI as you're using deprecated code. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php

```
<?php include("../Connections/conn.php")?>                       
<?php

$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$date=$_POST['year'];
$class=$_POST['class'];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){



 $sql2="SELECT SUM(boarding)as boarding,SUM(exam_paper)as 
 exam_paper,SUM(school_fee)as  
 school_fee,SUM(lunch)as lunch,SUM(trans_fee) as   
 trans_fee,idnumber,fname,class,section,boarding,term,date,year FROM payment
 WHERE YEAR(date) = '$date' AND fname like '%".$fname."%' AND class like 
'%".$class."%' AND    
 date like '%".$date."%' UNION  
 SELECT(boarding_setting,exampaper_setting,fee_setting,lunch_setting,
 trans_setting,year,date   
  ) 
FROM setting WHERE YEAR(date) = '$date' AND fname like '%".$fname."%' AND class 
like  '%".$class."%' AND date like '%".$date."%'"; 

$q=mysql_query($sql2);  

  }
else{
$sql="SELECT * FROM payment";
$q=mysql_query($sql);
  }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Far as I know  UNION must extract the same number of fields in both SELECTS, your first query has 10 fields and the second one has 7.

Does your script produce any errors ?

I agree with Binary101010 that you are using deprecated code and it is vulnerable to SQL Injection, at least use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on input you get from the user.